# Can connecting of AC adaptor first into device, then into mains pose a risk of voltage spike?

Tags: power-supply, ac, switch-mode-power-supply

Manuals of several various electronic devices I came across recommend connecting their AC adaptor first into the device, then into mains. I always thought the reverse order is safer because I thought that connecting into mains can send a voltage spike into already connected device. Are power supplies (adaptors of laptops or other electronics) designed in a way that there is no risk of harm to their device when connecting?
Are both connecting orders equally safe in these terms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are both connecting orders equally safe in these terms?

Depending on the equipment, in some cases the answer is **no**, the connecting orders are not necessarily equally safe, and the order can definitely matter. There *is* a reason why you found that "Manuals of several various electronic devices I came across recommend connecting their AC adaptor first into the device, then into mains."

During my research some years ago, the main issue I found is the LC-induced voltage spike, generated by the combination of the inductance of a typical switch-mode PSU's output filter and the cable going to the power supply "brick" (L) and the low ESR of (especially) ceramic input capacitors in the equipment (C).

Linear Technology have AppNote 88 which explains this better than I could write in a few paragraphs - ["Ceramic Input Capacitors Can Cause Overvoltage Transients"](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an88f.pdf).

In brief, the problem is that the *already established* voltage (e.g. 24 V in the Linear AppNote) is applied across an uncharged ceramic capacitor in the equipment (a simulated notebook PC power input circuit in the AppNote). In this situation, the capacitor has had *no chance* to (comparatively) *slowly* charge as the PSU voltage ramped-up, with the cable attached to the equipment, which would have happened in the "recommended" connection sequence. Instead it sees a step-change in input voltage when the PSU cable is attached. The result can be a voltage peak exceeding *twice* the input voltage. To quote from the AppNote:

"The input voltage transient problem is related to the powerup sequence. If the wall adapter is plugged into an AC outlet and powered up first, plugging the wall adapter output into a portable device can cause input voltage transients that could damage the DC/DC converters inside the device."

Another article with experiments which show the problem (although here they use a switch on a PCB at the end of a long cable to the PSU, rather than plugging-in a connector) is here by Pololu - ["Understanding Destructive LC Voltage Spikes"](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J16/all)

---

Summary - Unless there are any device-specific instructions to the contrary, it is less risky to connect the (unpowered) AC adapter first into the device, then into the mains, as you saw in those instruction manuals.

Comment: Nice find! It seems that laptop manufacturers at least have seen this AN and applied its wisdom to their products: I have been connecting my laptops to PSUs in random sequence for almost two decades now, and not a single one ever stopped working the moment I plugged it in.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening answer. I think some of my laptops which after some time got problems with their motherboards could possibly run into them also due to this thing, because I was consistently connecting the adaptor first into mains.

Answer (score 4):

For a properly designed PSU it shouldn't matter which connection you make first. For badly designed PSUs, both situation pose a risk:

- connecting the PSU to mains first may be problematic if PSU is designed to **regulate under load**. Typically, without load a PSU can output higher voltage that specified, damaging the device you will connect afterwards
- connecting the PSU to mains after the device is connected causes trouble if the **isolation/grounding** circuit is not designed properly. This may cause a short voltage spike to the device when the whole lot is connected to mains. Note that bad isolation/grounding could also pose a risk when you connect anything to the device later on, or touch conductive parts of it, and such equipment should be avoided altogether if possible.

In short, I would expect any decent PSU to work correctly regardless of what is connected first, but respect whatever order is specified in the manual for unusual / expensive / old equipment.